# How to add an additional ethernet support to stm32mp157d-dk1 board?

Tags: stm32, ethernet

How can I connect an external Ethernet module as a second Ethernet port to stm32mp157d-dk1 board? Is there any available ethernet module to use with stm32mp157d-dk1 board?

The project I am working on requires two ethernet ports. I want to add an additional ethernet port to the stm32mp157d-dk1 board.

Answer (score 1):

Add one using SPI interface. For example using w5500 IC

[image]